# how can i change the x position while jumping on air using c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a character controller which jumps but while jumping i want to change the x position of the character so basically he can turn while jumping, this is my attempt so far

```
     //start of character controller
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {

     //get the player vector movement vector
         movePlayer = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x,0,1);
         //float h = Input.acceleration.x;
         //translate the players movement
         transform.Translate(movePlayer * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         //the run animation
         animation.CrossFade("run");

    //restrict the movement of x-axis for player
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -3.0f, 3.0f);
    transform.position = pos;

   if (Input.GetButton("Jump")){
    //my ptoblem is here, the x axis on the vector3 is not happening    
    movePlayer =transform.TransformDirection(new   Vector3(Input.acceleration.x,jumpSpeed,forwardJumpSpeed)); 


              }  

         }

    // attach the gravity and move controller     
    movePlayer.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(movePlayer * Time.deltaTime);
```

**current code:**

```
void Update() {

    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

         //get the player vector movement vector
         movePlayer = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0,1);
         //float h = Input.acceleration.x;
         //translate the players movement
         transform.Translate(movePlayer * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         //the run animation
         animation.CrossFade("run");

    //restrict the movement of x-axis for player
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -3.0f, 3.0f);
    transform.position = pos;

    if (controller.isGrounded) {

   if (Input.GetButton("Jump")){

    movePlayer =transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x,jumpSpeed,forwardJumpSpeed)); 


              }


         }

     movePlayer.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(movePlayer * Time.deltaTime);
```

this is my current code, the jump if statement is inside the if(controller.isGrounded) the character still moves but when i press spacebar it deosnt jump anymore.

Comment: i commented where my problem is by the way, and plus all the code works fine!

Comment: Why do you have a `Controller.Move()` and a `transfrom.Translate()`?

Comment: yeh i know i thought that was the problem, sorry i removed the transform.translate and kept the controller.move(), but its still not jumping i tried putting a print statement("we are grounded"), after the if(controller.isGrounded) and its not printing so basically unity is not detecting the ground for us, wierd

Comment: The code seems fine but something is wrong in your scene. Also, have you assigned a gravity value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the player jumps its no longer grounded so any code under the `if(controller.isGrounded)` is not called. Put your movement code outside it but keep the jumping code inside it and it'll work fine.

```
// movement code goes here

// Keep the jumping code inside this if-statement
if (controller.isGrounded) {
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump")){  
       movePlayer =transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x,jumpSpeed,forwardJumpSpeed)); 
    }
```

Comment: the character is not jumping anymore when i press the spacebar! :)

Comment: when i press Spacebar, the character deosnt go up the y axis like before, but when i move the movement code inside the isGrounded it works :))

Comment: when i remove the movement code outside the isGrounded the jumping deosnt work, its wierd, but i think it might be something the controller.move command at the buttom

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Can you update the question with your current code?